# MongoDB findByID not works , but find ALL works

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query

I try to make a CRUD api on mongodb with node,js
I can use find all now, nut somehow , findByID isn't work
I follow [this one](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) 
and [this one](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/) , it just not work , help please

code

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
db.collection('songs',function(err, collection) {
collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
  res.send(items);
});
});\\\this one works
};

   var id = req.params.id;
   console.log('Retrieving song: ' + id);
   db.collection('songs', function(err, collection) {
   collection.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item) {
  res.send(item);
  });
});
};
\\this one not work
```

error

```
c:\Users\awei\WebstormProjects\untitled\routes\girlshanlder.js:23
db.collection.findOne('_id',function(err, collection) {
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined
   at c:\Users\awei\WebstormProjects\untitled\routes\girlshanlder.js:27:15
   at Db.collection (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:445:27)
   at exports.findById (c:\Users\awei\WebstormProjects\untitled\routes\girlshanlder.js:26:6)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at next (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
   at param (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:349:14)
   at param (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
   at Function.process_params (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
   at next (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
   at expressInit (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:33:5)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at trim_prefix (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
   at c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
db.collection('songs', function(err, collection) {
   collection.findOne({_id: `someId`}, function(err, items) {
       res.send(items);
```

Comment: thanks you for respone , I think it works !
but some how , I type http://localhost:3000/findByID/56c2046ea2c2094c1a5b5cd3
it can't show data

Comment: exports.findByID =  function(req, res) {
db.collection('songs', function(err, collection) {
  collection.findOne({_id:req}, function(err, items) {
    res.send(items);
  });
});
};

Comment: @AweiHsue, if the value of `req` is `localhost:3000/findByID/56c2046ea2c2094c1a5b5cd3`, please try to retrive the `id` from `req`.

Comment: my value is id : 56c2046ea2c2094c1a5b5cd3 (this one)
I though collection.findOne({_id:req} means find by the value which we type in browser right?
so i type localhost:3000/findByID/56c2046ea2c2094c1a5b5cd3
   56c2046ea2c2094c1a5b5cd3 is the req right? I'm not sure , please help

Comment: @AweiHsue, what the type of `56c2046ea2c2094c1a5b5cd3 `? maybe you should try to convert it into `ObjectID` through `new ObjectId(req)`...

Comment: I'm just want to make an API than find item by ID , type int in browser , your code works , just don't know what should i type in browser

Comment: http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/
I follow this one not work :(

Answer (score 0):

OK , I find the answer , this on work!

> var BSON = require('bson').BSONPure